# Rename the mpp file column programmatically

Tags: c#, ms-project

I have created a project to create a Microsoft Project file (.mpp) using C#.
Now I want to change the column header text programmatically.
By default the columns names are `Task Name`, `Duration`, `Start`, `End`, etc.

I want to change the `Task Name` column header text to some other value. In other words, instead of displaying `Task Name` I want `Description`.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: What API are you using to create the MPP file?

Answer (score 1):

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.ApplicationClass projectApp =new new Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.ApplicationClass();
```

....Do some stuff fro opeing a new file etc...

```
projectApp.TableEdit("Entry", true, false, Type.Missing, "Text3", "Text3", "Text3", "Schedule Name",20, Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.PjAlignment.pjLeft,
                    true, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,1 , Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
projectApp.TableApply("Entry");
```